# ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.13 error with Measurement setTool() function

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

When upgrading to 3.13 the following code to disable the measurement tool returns an error:

```
measurement.setTool("distance", false);
```

Here is the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'domNode' of undefined

When I switch back to 3.12 it works fine. I'm thinking it's a bug in 3.13, but wanted to see if anyone else has run across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the `setTool()` method was being called before `startup()`. It appears that starting with 3.13 you must call `startup()` before `setTool()`.

My application was built in a way where `setTool()` was being called to disable the measurement tool, even if it was not active. Prior to 3.13 that worked fine, but it seems that has changed.